Can I use ubuntu ar M2 PRO Chip native?
Can I use Ubuntu on Apple computers with M1 Chip natively?

No. But you can use Asahi Linux based on Fedora instead https://asahilinux.org/. It supports M1 and M2 chips very well. Asahi can be installed and uninstalled with just one command in MacOS. See https://github.com/AsahiLinux/docs/wiki/M1-Series-Feature-Support and https://github.com/AsahiLinux/docs/wiki/M2-Series-Feature-Support

Does this answer your question? Ubuntu Virtual Machine on a Apple Silicon (M1) macOS Host?
